# approximateCount not available in the search's response of OneDrive API/ SDK

Tags: office365, onedrive

As per the specs, I should be getting @search.approximateCount field when I perform search in OneDrive. However, when I use below code/ API call:

```
var response = await client.Me.Drive.Root.Search(searchText).Request().GetAsync();
GET /drive/root/search(q='vacation')
```

I am not able to find any approximate count attribute? How can I get this count?

Comment: Could you provide a link to the specs you mentioned? I'm unable to find any reference to approximateCount in the documentation.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT: Please see response section of this link: https://dev.onedrive.com/items/search.htm

Comment: Thank you, I understand the confusion now. This isn't supported in the Graph implementation. I'll remove that tag from your question since it isn't applicable here.

Comment: Are you querying OneDrive for Business or Consumer?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @KashifTahir: I am performing query on OneDrive for Business and OneDrive Personal.